# Fetching the data from cassandra table takes more time for dataSet when compared to rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

// Fetching data from Cassandra table using RDD for 20k records

```
println(Rdd.count()
val startTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()

var Rdd= sc.cassandraTable[Class]("Keyspace", "Table").keyBy(f => f.partition_key)

val endTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()    
val durationSeconds = (endTimeMillis - startTimeMillis)     
println("fetch  "+durationSeconds)    
println(Rdd.count())
```

//Storing the data obtained in rdd into a table in Cassandra. which is the copy of the above for 20k records

```
    val startTimeMillisinsert = System.currentTimeMillis()  
    Rdd.saveToCassandra("Keyspace", "Table")
    val stopTimeMillisinsert = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val durationSecondsinsert = (stopTimeMillisinsert - 
startTimeMillisinsert) 
    println("insert  "+durationSecondsinsert)
```

// Fetching data from Cassandra table using dataset for 20k records

```
   println(r1.count)
   val startTimeMillis1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
   var r1= spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                          .options(Map("table" ->"TableName","keyspace" ->"keySpaceName"))
```

.load()
  .where("Partition_key ='fa1eb916-67a3-46ed-8ea4- 045d43a49cdb'").as[Class]

```
  val durationSeconds = (endTimeMillis1 - startTimeMillis1)
  println("fetch "+durationSeconds)
```

//Storing the data obtained in dataset into a table in

Cassandra which is the copy of the above for 20k records

```
    val startTimeMillis1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    r.write
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .cassandraFormat("Table","Keyspace")
    .mode(SaveMode.Append).save()

    val endTimeMillis1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val durationSecondsinsert= (endTimeMillis1 - startTimeMillis)
   println("insert  "+durationSecondsinsert)
```

OUTPUT:

```
For DataSet
21299
fetch  9207
insert  62410 

For RDD
21299
fetch  473
insert  23326
```

Comment: Spark SQL will take more time than Spark Core API. I don't think this behavior is wrong at all. What is your expectation?

Comment: But as I have read from many sites I could understand that datasets are faster in writes when compared to rdd's. Also, can you please explain why it takes datasets more time to fetch than rdds.

Comment: Which Cassandra version are you using and are you using Spark Cassandra connector? I did a bit research and found https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/issues/200 where it states the connector causes delay in fetching and writing in Cassandra.

Comment: The configurations I am using are :[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.0.1855 | DSE 5.1.3 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]

Comment: I dont think spark cassandra connector is the problem as we are using it for both rdd and dataset.